# Combo Box Tabstop getting double focus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

When I tab through my combo-boxes, they are triggering two tab stops.

### Tab #1

The inner content gets selected:

[image: Inner content selected]

### Tab #2

The entire control gets selected:

[image: Outer content selected]

### Combo Box XAML

```
<ComboBox
            IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
            x:Name="dd_Client"
            TabIndex="3"            
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding}"
            DisplayMemberPath="client"
            SelectedItem="{Binding}"
            Width="121"
         Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="63.825,2.44,0,1.96" IsReadOnly="True" IsManipulationEnabled="True"/>
```

I tried adding `IsTabStop=False` and `Focusable=False` to the combobox XAML. This removed the Tab#1 behavior above and kept #2. However, I was no longer able to do a text search selection within the combobox (which I need).

Comment: It seems a theme/style I'm using at the app.xaml level is overriding the default behavior of the combo box. Currently trying to figure out where it is being overridden.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue recently. As it turned out, I was applying a textBlock over the comboBox. As a result that focus was shifted. When you change the selection of the comboBox to another option and try to do the same thing, does it double focus then?

Comment: What do you mean by "change the selection of the comboBox to another option "? When I add those properties I mentioned above to the XAML it doesn't double focus. I basically need to remove Tab#2 behavior somehow.